# EF create index on large table blocks database

Tags: sql, entity-framework, model-view-controller, indexing

I created some indexes on some large SQL tables (200.000 records) using EF (model first) but the problem is that when I publish the change in Production and the migration that applies the indexes is run the webapp blocks for a long period of time. How can I avoid this in the future?

Comment: TBH 200.000 records is not that large SQL table (though it depends on number of columns and data stored in them). Can you please share some more info (which indexes, how they are set up, what db engine are you using). Also generate the SQL migration script and see if something catches the eye.

Answer (score 0):

> I publish the change in Production and the migration that applies the indexes is run the webapp blocks for a long period of time.

The [recommended way to apply migrations is with SQL Scripts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/migrations/applying?tabs=dotnet-core-cli).  If possible, deploy these changes during an outage.  If you have to apply these changes while the application is online, have a DBA examine the change script to ensure it's suitable for applying to a busy online database.  EG for SQL Server using [ONLINE index creation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-index-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#online---on--off-).